# Open Ball in a Metric Space vs. Open Set in a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, intuition

I'm having trouble understanding the notion of an open set when applied to a space without a metric defined on it. I have read that all metric spaces are naturally a topological space, but the converse is not true. Topological spaces definitions I have read use the idea of open sets, and I can't understand this abstract idea of openness or closedness of a set without having a notion of distance.

I can understand the notion of open and closed sets in a *metric* space from the definitions I have read using the idea of distance and open balls. So for example given a metric space $M$ with the metric $d$, we can say a set $U \subset M$ is open if $\forall x \in U, \exists B(x,r) \subset U$, which says that we can choose any point within the set $U$ and there will always be some sufficiently small distance $r$ that we can move in any direction to another point $y$ that is also contained within $U$. This has an intuitive conceptual meaning in my head regardless of space $M$ or metric $d$.

Now take the example of a space $F$, a fruit bowl with $3$ apples, $3$ oranges and $2$ bananas. There is no metric defined on the space $F$ to determine a distance between its elements, the fruit. Can we define an open set on this space? In order to be a topological space we need to be able to define open sets right?

Comment: Let $X$ be a set. Any collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying certain conditions can be declared to be the set of open subsets of $X$. This choice is what gives $X$ the structure of a topological space. It's the same way that to define a group, you just need a binary operation $*$ on a set $G$ (meeting certain conditions). There are many possible ways to select an operation on a set that turn it into a group.

Comment: In your example, it would be possible to declare that every subset of $F$ is open (thus giving $F$ what's called the *discrete* topology). Or that the only open subsets of $F$ are $F$ and $\emptyset$ (the *trivial* topology).

Comment: @amirbahadory No, that is definitely not how we define it, as it would be circular.

Comment: The most general way to define a topology on your set $F$ would be to take any collection of subsets $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$ of $F$, and to declare a subset of $F$ to be *open* if and only if it can be written as a union of intersections of the sets $E_i$. (If $F$ were not assumed finite, we would need to allow infinitely many sets $E_i$ and allow arbitrary unions of finite intersections of them.)

Comment: @amirbahadory I did not say it was false. I said that is not how we define it as it would be circular (you are using open sets to define what an open set is)

Comment: So Keith following your definition, I could choose for example $E_1 = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ as the set of apples, $E_2 = \{o_1, o_2\}$, as the set of oranges, and $E_3 = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ as the set of bananas in the fruit bowl. So we have $E_i \subset F, i = 1,2,3$, and then $E_i \cap E_k = \emptyset$, for $i \neq k$, and  $E_i \cap E_k = E_i$, for $i = k$, so I can say that: $T = \{\emptyset, E_1, E_2, E_3\}$ is a set collection of open sets in F. Does that mean that T is a topology on F? What if I chose the set of ALL subsets of F, the powerset?

Comment: No, I said the open sets were all *unions* of intersections. (We must agree to regard $F$ as the intersection of an empty family of $E_i$'s, and we agree that the union of an empty family of sets is $\emptyset$.) Yes, the power set example works. That's what's called the *discrete* topology.

Comment: Look, I know this doesn't answer your question about having some intuition for how this relates to continuity. The best advice I can offer in this case is to go carefully through the definitions and the proofs of the basic propositions concerning topological spaces, especially those concerning limits and continuity, thinking carefully about how the various things would translate in a metric space, where, as you mentioned, the open subsets are *defined* in a certain way. Eventually, you will gain some intuition about the ways in which general topological spaces can differ from metric spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think I see my mistake above, the set $T = \{\emptyset , E_1 , E_2 , E_3 , \{a_1 , a_2 , a_3 , o_1 , o_2 \}, \{a_1 , a_2 , a_3 , b_1 , b_2 , b_3 \},\{o_1 , o_2 , b_1, b_2 , b_3 \}\}$ would be the set of all unions of intersections for my chosen sets. Could you just ell me, could I define T then as a topology on F, and $x \in T$ as open sets?

Comment: I can see drawing it out how there is an idea of connectedness, such that two elements belonging to the same open set are "connected" by that set, and that for the discrete topology, each element of F is directly connected to every other element of F by these sets, but if this is the concept behind it, I think it's confusing to use the words 'open set' and instead something like 'connected set' or 'parent set' would make more sense to me - wikipedia gives 2 definitions of a topological space; in terms of open sets, and in terms of closed sets.....but I'm probably still missing something

Comment: You forgot to include $F$ itself, which is also open. You talk about two elements belonging to "the same (basic) open set." This concept only really makes sense because you happened to pick your $E_i's$ disjoint. The word "open" is not wrong at all. If you continue to study the initial definitions and theorems concerning interior, closure, and continuity, you will see that the definitions work out to be the same, if you happen to be in the special case of dealing with a metric space. This is an ex post facto justification for calling these sets "open."

Comment: OK, well I'm trying to read as much as I can, but most of the definitions seem to be circular, e.g. Wikipedia definition using open sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_sets_definition) ...that we call the collection of subsets of a set X, 'open sets' if they satisfy axioms that the empty set and X are both open, the union of open sets is open, and the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open. I can't find a good definition of the term 'open set' that does not say "it is 'open' if a condition exists involving a set that is open"...

Comment: e.g. the answer below by "Remember me" that says A is open if it is the intersection of it's superset, Y in X, and another 'open' set, U in X

Comment: You shouldn't expect any reference to say "in a topological space, *this* is what an open set is." As I alluded to above, this is akin to expecting a definition of what the binary operation in a group is, when in fact on any set there are many possible group laws. However, if you wish to define a *particular* topological space, then yes, you will need to say (directly or indirectly) what the open sets are in that space, and check that the axioms are satisfied. I don't suggest Wikipedia as a main source for learning topology. Perhaps have a look at Vol. 2 of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich...

Comment: (cont'd) or *Real and Functional Analysis* by Serge Lang. You can learn the essentials of topology in one or two chapters. I recommend that you accept the definitions at face value at first, and connect them with what you know about metric spaces as you go along. (I just thought of better example: asking for the definition of an open set in an arbitrary topological space is analogous to asking "How do you define the distance between two points in a metric space?" The answer, of course, is that it is defined differently in different spaces. All you know is that certain axioms are satisfied.)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe an analogy will help. Supposing you start with an understanding of *Real Analysis*, you can generalize this understanding to *Metric Spaces*:

> In *Real Analysis*, you have this fixed notion of distance between two points in $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $|x-y|$. Then using this definition you build your collections of open sets that you use to study $\mathbb{R}$. These sets look like open intervals $(x-r, x+r)$ centered at $x$ with radius $r$, and using these open sets you can study the space (continuity, connectedness, derivatives, etc.)
>
> Then you jump to into a general a *Metric Space* and are told "Use whatever definition of *distance* that you like (as long as it follows a few rules to keep things sensible) and build your open sets with that!" Then you just proceed to do the same thing you did in *Real Analysis* only you are using open balls that look like $B(x,r)$, centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

Now we can see a related jump from understanding *Metric Spaces* to understanding *General Topology*:

> In *Metric Spaces*, you have this fixed notion of distance between two points in your space $X$ defined as $d(x,y)$. Then using this definition you build your collections of open sets that you use to study $X$. These sets look like open balls $B(x,r)$ centered at $x$ with radius $r$, and using these open sets you can study the space (continuity, connectedness, derivatives, etc.)
>
> Then you jump to into *General Topology* and are told "You don't need to bother  *building* the collection of open sets at all. Instead, I'm just going to hand you this collection of open sets! (and these open sets will follow a few rules to keep things sensible)" Then you just proceed to do the same thing you did with *Metric Spaces* only you are using these open sets that you were handed to you, and there might not be a easy way to describe what they look like.

Answer (score 2):

Having some notion of open sets lets you define notions of points getting arbitrary close to each other, or continuity. For example in space of real functions you can choose topology (in other words: choose which sets you declare open) such that sequence of functions converges to some given function pointwise. There is no natural notion of distance related to this mode of convergence, yet it is clear that in SOME sense the converging functions are getting closer and closer. There are also other notions on closeness on such a space, for example you can say that sequence converges if convergence is uniform - and then you actually get familiar metric space. To understand topology you need a) to look for examples and b) notice that many notions in metric space theory can be defined only in terms of open sets and you will be able to extend them outside metric spaces if you define open sets abstractly. Then after some practice and experience you will notice that such generalisations are very natural in many contexts and topology is very powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give me some examples please especially of b) where some notions can only be expressed in terms of open sets and not open balls, as could be done in a metric space?

Comment: @Nabla The point of (b) is that when you look at the general topological definitions of, say, *connectedness* or *continuity* of a function, these definitions are in terms of open **sets**. These **sets** don't have to be **balls** like they would be in the case that you're studying a metric space. So when you define *connectedness* or *continuity* of a function for metric spaces, the fact that these definitions talk about open **balls** is incidental; the important part is that they're open.

Answer (score -1):

Take a set $X$. Let $\lambda \in X$ , we say that a ball of radius epsilon ($\epsilon$) around the point $\lambda$ will be an open set iff $\ni$ a point $k\notin X$ such that a neighborhood of radius delta ($\delta$) around the point $k$ is not in the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $\lambda$.

In mathematical terms , $B_\epsilon(\lambda)$ is open when,$$N_\delta(k) \cap B_\epsilon(\lambda)=\emptyset.$$

If you want to think in terms of a topological space:
We say that let $Y\subset X$ , then given a set $A$ in $Y$ we say that it is open if 
$A=Y\cap U$ where $U$ is open in $X$

Comment: Talking about a "ball of radius $\epsilon$" is only meaningful in a metric space, but Nabla's question is about topological spaces other than metric spaces. The last part of your answer shows how, given a topology on a space $X$, you can define a topology in a natural way on any subset $Y$ of $X$. I also don't think that's what Nabla is asking about.