# Open set ambiguity

Tags: general-topology

I decided to learn topology from a [publicly available document](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf), however, I have come across a concept that seems to be defined twice in two different ways. At one point in the document it defines a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to be open if every point in it has a neighborhood (my simplification for the purpose of conciseness). In another place, it has the following text (this is when defining a topological space): "A topological space is a set X together with a collection O of subsets of
X , *called open sets* , such that..." (then the text lists the three axioms of topological spaces), which one may interpret as defining open sets to be sets satisfying the axioms of a topological space, hence my confusion. Thanks in advance

Comment: The first definition you mention regarding neighborhoods is one of the equivalent definitions for open sets for the *usual* topology.  The later definition is the more generic definition used for when we might want to talk about a more exotic topology than the usual one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Ball in a Metric Space vs. Open Set in a Topological Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348026/open-ball-in-a-metric-space-vs-open-set-in-a-topological-space)

Answer (score 0):

Elements of the topology are called open sets. For your example $\Bbb R$, it is actually the Euclidean Topology, and the open sets are basically the open intervals.

Comment: But are the open sets as defined in the first definition I referenced the only ones that fit the axioms? There doesn't seem to be a way to deduce the properties of open sets in the first definition from the axioms of topological spaces

Answer (score 0):

A set, $X$, can have multiple different ways to be a topological space. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ can have the "standard topology," where open sets are as defined in the first part of your question, but we can also give it the "discrete topology," where *any* subset is open.

Both these "topologies" (ie collections of open sets) satisfy the axioms, and make $\mathbb{R}$ a topological space in different ways. The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is just an *example* of a topological space, and certainly not the only one.